# Números amigos en C

Tags: c

Tengo este programa que no tira error pero simper da que no son números amigos aunque los números ingresados SI sean amigos.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int numeros_amigos(int x, int y){
    int suma_x=0;
    int suma_y=0;
    int i, k;
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++){
        if (x%i==0)
            suma_x+=i;
    }
    for (k = 1; k <= y; k++){
        if (y%k==0)
            suma_y+=k;
    }
    return ((suma_x==y) && (suma_y==x));
}   

int main(){
    int n_1, n_2;
    printf("Introduzca el nº 1: ");
    scanf("%d",&n_1);
    printf("Introduzca el nº 2: ");
    scanf("%d",&n_2);

    if (numeros_amigos(n_1,n_2))
        printf ("¡Son amigos! :)");
    else
        printf ("No son amigos :(");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola Alejandro. Puedes explicar qué son numeros *amigos*? Añade tambien ejemplos de numeros y el output que deberia tener y el que realemente obtienes. Has hecho debug para ver donde puede estar fallando ? Mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Aquí esta la descripción de lo que se entiende por número amigo https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Números_amigos

Comment: el enlace está bien pero igualmente has de mejorar la explicación de la pregunta. Pon ejemplos para ver qué test estás haciendo y ver qué puede ir mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que un número amigo no debe considerar al mismo número como divisor, entonces cambia tus `for` para que no incluyan al propio número.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int numeros_amigos(int x, int y){
int suma_x=0;
int suma_y=0;
int i, k;
for (i = 1; i < x; i++){
    if (x%i==0)
        suma_x+=i;
}
for (k = 1; k < y; k++){
    if (y%k==0)
        suma_y+=k;
}
return ((suma_x==y) && (suma_y==x));
}   

int main(){
 int n_1, n_2;
 printf("Introduzca el nº 1: ");
 scanf("%d",&n_1);
 printf("Introduzca el nº 2: ");
 scanf("%d",&n_2);

 if (numeros_amigos(n_1,n_2))
    printf ("¡Son amigos! :)");
 else
    printf ("No son amigos :(");
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Le cambie un par de cosas a tu codigo, para hacerlo mas sencillo. Con muy poco se podia solucionar tu problema.

Recordemos que los numeros amigos son aquellos, que la suma de sus divisores es igual al otro numero y viceversa. Un ejemplo serian 220 y 284.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int i;
int numeros_amigos(int x, int y){
for(i=2;i<x;i++){
    if(x % i==0){
        y=y+i;
    }
}
return x,y;
}   

int main(){
int n_1, n_2;
int s1=1, s2=1;
printf("Introduzca el nº 1: ");
scanf("%d",&n_1);
printf("Introduzca el nº 2: ");
scanf("%d",&n_2);
s1=numeros_amigos(n_1,s1);
s2=numeros_amigos(n_2,s2);

if((s1==n_2)&&(s2==n_1)) {

    printf ("¡Son amigos! :)");
    system("pause");
}
else{
    printf ("No son amigos :(");
    system("pause");
}
return 0;
}
```